# How do I patch a class in the same file as a class under test, that is initialized before the test begins?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-decorators

(Nota bene: This is heavily modified from the original question, to include details I erroneously elided.)

This is the (summarized) file (`common.py`) I'm testing. It contains a decorator (derived from the [`Decorum` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Decorum)) that calls a class method on another object(`A`): I want to patch out `A`, because that code makes an external call I'm not testing.

```
from decorum import Decorum


class A:
    @classmethod
    def c(cls):
        pass


class ClassyDecorum(Decorum):
    """Hack to allow decorated instance methods of a class object to run with decorators.
    Replace this once Decorum 1.0.4+ comes out.
    """

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        from functools import partial
        return partial(self.call, instance)


class B(Decorum):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        A.c()
        return super().init(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'd like to [`@patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) class `A` in my unittest, to isolate and check `B.d()`'s functionality. This is my unittest (located in `test/test_common.py`):

```
class BDecoratedClass(MagicMock):

    @B
    def dummy_func(self):
        return "Success"

class TestB(TestCase):
    @patch('unittest_experiment.A', autospec=True)
    def test_d(self, mock_a):
        b = BDecoratedClass()
        b.dummy_func()
        mock_a.c.assert_called_once_with()  # Fails
```

Debugging the above, I see that `A` is never actually mocked: the code proceeds into `A`'s code, so it makes sense that `mock_a` is never called, and thus the assertion fails. However, I'd like to properly monkey patch `A`. This approach works if I'm monkey patching an import that exists in `common.py`, but apparently not if the class is defined there?

Note that I think this is likely an issue of *where* I'm patching, that is `@patch('common.A', autospec=True)` should more likely be something like `@patch('where.python.actually.finds.A.when.B.calls.A', autospec=True)`. But I'm very unclear on how to determine if that is the case, and if so, what the correct path is. For instance, `@patch('BDecorated.common.A', autospec=True)` does not work.

Comment: @wim The original sample code was too simplified. My bad. I've updated with an appropriate minimal, testable, verifiable example.

Comment: This sounds like you've got some sort of import weirdness you're not showing us. For example, if `A` is actually defined in a different file and `from` imported, or if you've made one of the common mistakes with packages and ended up with the same file getting imported as two modules.

Comment: What is `b.d`? I don't see any such method.

Comment: @user2357112 I've replicated the exact example above: the classes are in the files as indicated. I agree, though, that it appears the module being mocked is 'somewhere different' than the module being called in `init()`.

Comment: Okay, with the edit, that looks like a completely different problem. I'm not familiar with the `decorum` library you're using, but `B.init` most likely gets called when the decorator is applied, not when the decorated method gets called.

Comment: You're too late to mock anything. The functionality you wanted to test finished running long before your test executed.

Comment: Ah! That... makes sense. Any chance you have links to resources describing the best ways to cope with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: @user2357112 Moved the dummy import inside the test function, and that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like patch substitutes the import and that's why it's too late at that point unless you work around it like you explained in your the answer. I found that using `patch.object` for individual methods also work. So something like:

```
class TestB(TestCase):
    @patch.object(A, 'c')
    def test_d(self, mock_c):
        b = BDecoratedClass()
        b.dummy_func()
        mock_c.assert_called_once_with()  # Succeeds
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), I arrived at this solution. Caveat: I don't know if this is standard or 'best' practice, but it seems to work.

First, move the `BDecoratedClass` to it's own file in `test/dummy.py`. Then change the test to this:

```
class TestB(TestCase):
    @patch('common.A', autospec=True)
    def test_d(self, mock_a):
        from test.dummy import BDecoratedClass

        b = BDecoratedClass()
        b.dummy_func()
        mock_a.c.assert_called_once_with()  # Succeeds
```

This forces the patch to execute prior to the import of the dummy class being decorated. It's a little weird because the import is inside the function, but for a test that seems fine.

*Bigger Caveat*:

This only works for the first test that imports something from the module where, in this case `BDecoratedClass` imports from. At that juncture everything else in the class has been loaded and cannot be patched.